# Ubuntu Firefox tab navigation

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard, browser-tabs, navigation

Is there a way to change the key sequence that triggers a forward / back tab navigation in Firefox? I browsed about:config,but couldn't find anything. I'm not a fan of the CTRL + TAB / CTRL + SHIFT + TAB. It is just way to crowded for me. I'd much rather change it to CTRL + { / CTRL + }, like it is on OSX. It feels much more balanced to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Key Config extension](http://mozilla.dorando.at/readme.html)

Alternatively, you can also use Ctrl + Pg Up / Ctrl + Pg Down for navigation.

Comment: Ctrl + Page Up/Down it is! Also, Ctrl + Shift + Page Up/Down lets you rearrange your tabs! :]